# How to Create a Jacobian Function with the input as functions of 2 variables

Tags: functions

```
J[x_Function, y_Function] :=
Module[xu, xv, yu, yv]
xu = D[x, u];
xv = D[x, v];
yu = D[y, u];
yv = D[y, v];
matrix = {{xu, xv}, {yu, yv}};
jacobian = Det[matrix];
Print["The Jacobian is " <> ToString[jacobian]]
```

This is supposed to give the Jacobian for the change of variables `x = x(u,v)` and `y = y(u,v)`, however if I input functions of `u` and `v` for `x` and `y`, it just returns

```
J[u + v, u - v]
```

Please help.

Comment: The module should be `Module[{xu, xv, yu, yv},...]`.

Comment: `u + v` has head `Plus`, not head `Function` that you specified, so it is not valid argument for your function. Same for `u - v`.

Answer (score 2):

The function `D` can directly compute Jacobian matrix

```
D[{x[u, v], y[u, v]}, {{u, v}}]
```

For your specific case

```
D[{u + v, u - v}, {{u, v}}]
Det[%]
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}
>
> -2

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntactical problems with the provided code-as noted in the comments- but apart from that, it would be possible to perform the same operations as the ones in the Q, with evaluating something that would eventually get to a form such as `J[#1+#2&,#1-#2&]` in order to accommodate the definition of `J`.

`J` is defined in such a way as to receive two arguments which have head `Function`. In the code example of the Q, `J[u+v,u-v]` does not evaluate as expected because the provided arguments have `Head` `Plus` not `Function` (as already pointed to in the comments). Here, the arguments passed to `J` are '*functions*'.

Now, I am not sure you will be happy with this iteration of your code either, because-in all likelihood-those `x` and `y`s are already defined in terms of `u` and `v` and you'll have to rewrite them in terms of `Slots` `#1` and `#2` (rewrite them as pure functions in order for them to 'play nice' with the initial def. of `J`.)

Also, in this case, the remaing of the code needs refactoring too eg something like `D[x, u]` would have to be re- written as `D[x[u,v],u]` to take into considetation the fact that `x` is in fact a pure function of two arguments etc.

Additionally, relevant to the possible code refactoring is the fact that you can construct the Jacobian matrix in a more compact way as displayed in another nice answer to your Q.

In closing, refactor the code either to allow `J` to accept expressions other than `Function` as arguments or change the `x` and `y` functions to pure functions along with appropriate changes to the derivatives; also perhaps consider a more compact way for writing the Jacobian.

Comment: But what my question really is is how to modify my code to make it produce the right Jacobian, because I'm not that good with pure functions

Comment: Hello @SamTHEDuck999! You could try defining `J` in a way that doesn't restrict its arguments to be pure functions (lose the `_Function` pattern), as I have already alluded to in my answer and perhaps edit your question with any additional issues you encounter during the refactoring process.